# ssl error Google drive api

Tags: php, ssl, curl, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using PHP library to retrieve files or upload them to Google drive

```
include_once ROOT.'/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$credentialsFile = ROOT.'/google-api-php-client/service_account.json';
if (!file_exists($credentialsFile)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Service account credentials Not Found!');
}

$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFile);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

/**
   * Проверка существования папки для документов
   */

$optParams = array(
  'q' => "name='Документы'"
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
exit('Нет папки для документов');
} else {
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
$papka_doc = $file->getId();
  }
 }
```

everything worked, but a few days ago, there was an error:

```
Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Firstly, you should download curl.cert file,

```
curl https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Secondly, set this certificate.

```
$client->getHttpClient()->setDefaultOption('verify', '[Certificate File Path]');
```

Centos default path;

```
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: unfortunately, this method did not help